# Jsoup connect to url, extract html after 200 ms

Tags: jsoup, wait, live

I am trying to extract live parameters from a website. The problem hereby is that when the webpage is loaded, all the parameters are initially = 'XXXX'. By consequence, when I use the following code, the output is 'XXXX'...

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).ignoreContentType(true).get();

Elements elem = doc.select("text[id=id_17]");
String par = elem.text();
Log.i("INFO", "parameter = " + par);
```

Only after a few milliseconds, the 'XXXX' is replaced by the actual values (e.g. 6.27) by an ecmascript.

Is it possible to 'wait' for a few milliseconds before I extract the values from the website?

Comment: Jsoup does not support JavaScript (or ecmaScript) so that won't work. You need to use some other way, perhaps with HtmlUnit or Selenium webdriver. If you post the url you are using, I could perhaps suggest a better way.

Comment: Thanks, I will look that up. I cannot post the url since it is a local webpage only accesible for devices connected to the wifi station in the factory I'm working.

Comment: In that case you could look what happens in the network tab of the browser dev console, the script is probably just loading some JSON into the page after those few seconds. In that case, you could find out where the JSON is loaded from, and then load it in your own app.

Comment: I was able to extract the required data. I don't know if it is efficient, but it works: I loaded the page up in a WebView, and called the function that I found in the web page source code as follows: webView.loadUrl("javascript:function(e){ ... }"). In this function I added a java method which writes the value in a TextView via a javascript interface. Anyway, thanks for your suggestions, they brought me to this solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Solution found by OP:

> I was able to extract the required data. I don't know if it is efficient, but it works: I loaded the page up in a WebView, and called the function that I found in the web page source code as follows:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:function(e){ ... }").
```

> In this function I added a java method which writes the value in a TextView via a javascript interface. Anyway, thanks for your suggestions, they brought me to this solution ;)